# how can I disable Apple's software updater in Win XP?

Tags: windows, apple, remove

I installed some Apple software (either Quicktime or Safari) on my computer.  I removed them both long ago, but I've been unable to disable those pesky "reminders" from Apple to upgrade my Apple software.  How can I remove the updater from my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reminders are usually a 'Scheduled Task' in Windows XP.

Click on 'Start', then 'All Programs', then 'Accessories', then 'System Tools' then 'Scheduled Tasks'.
There will generally be one in there called 'AppleSoftwareUpdate'.
You can delete this job, or alternatively double click it to change the schedule it runs to.